# Seaborn Heatmap Axis Format reverses Graph

Tags: seaborn, heatmap

When I add in the formatting of the x axis, the graph remains the same. When I format the y axis tick labels, the graph reverses and I can't figure out why.

Heatmap before y-axis format

[image: heatmap before y-axis format]

Here is the graph after the x-axis format

[image: heatmap after y-axis format]

```
ax = sns.heatmap(All_new, linewidths=.5, annot=True, cmap="RdYlGn")
plt.tight_layout()
plt.xlabel('Losing Digit')
plt.ylabel('Winning Digit')
plt.title('Total Distribution of Final Digits (%)')
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x))))
ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x))))
#ax.invert_yaxis()
plt.show()
```